# npm test -- --coverage never exits

Tags: node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, continuous-integration, frontend

I am using **create-react-app** to create a react application. When I executes **npm test -- --coverage** the test never exists. npm test actually runs **react-scripts test**. Any Idea?

[image]

Comment: Could you display the actual command that is running. It should be within the scripts object within the package.json.

if within the command you have -- try removing it. an example would be jest . --coverage

Comment: @connormcwood my script object is 
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }

Comment: There are lots of threads in relation to react-tests not terminating. You could try the following: set the value of the test to be CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom rather than just react-scripts test. See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1137

Comment: "test": "CI=true react-scripts test" solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: Quality, as the thread suggests, you have to state CI=true for some peculiar reason.

Comment: Not really a  peculiar reason.  In CI the test process must exit so the ci server can pick up the results. When running from the commandline the idea is that you let it open so you can do a testrun everytime you want to verify something. Hence it starts in watch mode and runs each time your code is saved.

Comment: Could you please add the command line output instead of a picture of it? See [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`-- --coverage` part won't work, and should use one of the commands below to set `CI` to `true`.

> By default npm test runs the watcher with interactive CLI. However, you can force it to run tests once and finish the process by setting an environment variable called CI.

[**source: React docs**](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#on-your-own-environment)

#### Windows (cmd.exe)

- `set CI=true && npm test`
- `set CI=true && npm run build`

#### Windows (Powershell)

- `($env:CI = "true") -and (npm test)`
- `($env:CI = "true") -and (npm run build)`

#### Linux, macOS (Bash)

- `CI=true npm test`
- `CI=true npm run build`

---

*NOT included in the docs*

#### For Docker (node and react):

`docker run -e CI=true [myImage] npm run test`

Comment: for (React) the source for the above answer: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#travis-ci

Answer (score 36):

Coverage won't work with Jest in watch mode.

Because "react-scripts test --env=jsdom" works in watch mode by default, the watch mode has to be switched off while generating the coverage output.

The following excerpt from the package.json contains a line "coverage" for illustration, how code coverage can be achieved within an app which was bootet by create-react-app.

It's just the modified "test" script, where the options **--watchAll=false** and **--coverage** are added in combination:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "coverage": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --watchAll=false --coverage",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Please note that it is obsolete to use standalone double-dash **--** .

Answer (score 5):

Most of the time this issue can be occur because of following reasons.

1. Not mentioning the required `npm-script` arguments in the
   `package.json` file. If you use `create-react-app` to create your
   react application, then it will not accept any command line
   arguments. To resolve this problem, add following line under the
   `script` tag in your `package.json`.

   ```
   "test": "react-scripts test --coverage --watchAll", //mark --watchAll=false if you want.
   ```
2. Not mentioning the required `jest` configuration arguments in
   the `package.json` or `jest.config.js` files. You should mention the files
   which needed to include in your test coverage under the jest
   configurations. Add following configurations in your
   `package.json`.

**package.json**

```
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.js",
      "!src/index.js", // files you need to avoid in test coverage
      "!src/hooks/*.js",
      "!src/context/*.js"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 90,
        "functions": 90,
        "lines": 90,
        "statements": 90
      }
    },
    "coverageReporters": [
      "html",
      "text"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

Specifying a directory worked in my case

```
"test:cover": "react-scripts test --coverage src"
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the solutions above, and for me it was still hanging with the message: `Ran all test suites.`.

But this little hack helped:

```
    "test:ci": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --forceExit --detectOpenHandles",
```

Explanation: The problem was coming from Jest not being able to close all processes. The above is a quick workaround. Ideally you should track the process that's stopping Jest from exiting.

Answer (score 0):

In my case just added a new script **"test:coverage": "react-scripts test --coverage"**

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:coverage": "react-scripts test --coverage",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
"scripts": {
 //* other scripts like start, build

 "test": "react-scripts test",
 "test:coverage": "react-scripts test --coverage --watchAll=false",
},
```

**Bonus point:**
Since running test with coverage takes time to generate coverages, so we can add two scripts one for normal test to know whether tests passed or failed and another to generate the coverage.

Now you can run test or test with coverage based on the usecases:

```
npm run test
npm run test:coverage
```