# how to get code coverage in react with react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have written unit tests using react testing library(@testing-library/react & @testing-library/dom) and jest-dom(@testing-library/jest-dom). I am able to run my tests successfully.

I am not using jest/jest-cli complete pacakge. I am using react testing library along with that jest-dom(@testing-library/jest-dom) it might be some sub pacakge or something i am not sure what to call it exactly.

How to get code coverage using react testing library?

[image]

Comment: `jest` has inbuilt coverage tool `Istanbul` built into it. You just need to use `npm run test --coverage`

Comment: Without installing jest/jest-cli is it not possible?  imean some thing with @testing-library/jest-dom

Comment: RTL does not collect coverage. That's the job of your test runner. Follow @SandipNirmal and @Harmenx's advice and run `npm run coverage`

Comment: An actual answer to this question exists: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991641/npm-test-coverage-never-exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991641/npm-test-coverage-never-exits)

Answer (score 38):

Well, **create-react-app** is giving you a lot out of the box but it is also imposing some constraints...

You can't just add the flag `--coverage` to `npm run test` because that script is already running your tests in watch mode (and things like running only failed tests and other things that you can do in the interactive mode would affect your coverage report anyway).

So first thing first, run your test in single run mode.

```
CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom
```

And because you already have a test task in your package.json you can simplify your task as so:

```
CI=true npm test -- --env=jsdom
```

Alright, we are getting closer...
So now, on top of that add the `--coverage` flag and you are all set:

```
CI=true npm test -- --env=jsdom --coverage
```

To summarize your npm task could be like:

```
"test:coverage": "CI=true npm test -- --env=jsdom --coverage"
```

And you will see your report in the terminal and the `coverage` folder will be generated, where you can see a lot of useful info, by the way!

Comment: To make the answer environment independent you can also use `cross-env` npm package: `cross-env CI=true npm test -- --env=jsdom --coverage`. Otherwise it requires different syntax on Windows.

Comment: Can someone please explain the syntax `CI=true` => this sets an environment variable, `CI=true npm test` what does this do? i thought it would have been something like `CI=true && npm test`. Also what does `<space>--</space>` means?

Comment: @blogbydev `CI=true` in `npm test` runs the tests once and forces it to finish afterwards. You'll notice that when you run `npm test` locally it runs in watcher mode with interactive CLI. The double dashes are a way of passing the arguments that follow to the commands called by the main command

Answer (score 10):

An actual answer to this question exists: [npm test -- --coverage never exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991641/npm-test-coverage-never-exits)

The RTL doesn't provide testing coverage stats, but Jest does if you add the following to `package.json`:

`"test:coverage": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --watchAll=false --coverage"`

Then you can run:

`npm run test:coverage`

See either the answer I link to above or Watchmaker's answer even further above for more details.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me until I added the `test:coverage` script to my `package.json` following @Watchmakers answer above.

Comment: Good catch @Raystorm, I forgot the JSON part.

Answer (score 9):

Since `react-scripts` has incorporated `jest` configuration, you can just type in 
`npm run test --coverage` or `yarn test --coverage`, to generate coverage report.