# Npm run test on azure pipelines does not return

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops

On my Azure Pipeline, I have the following task:

```bash
- script:
    npm run test --watch=false --loglevel verbose --single
    displayName: npm run tests
```

I run it on an Ubuntu agent with Puppeteer. The tests run successfully:

```
Chrome Headless 111.x (Linux x86_64): Executed 16 of 16 SUCCESS (0.222 secs / 0.198 secs)
TOTAL: 16 SUCCESS
```

However, the task never returns, so it stays there until the whole build times out, as configured to do. It seems that it does not realize that the job has finished to run in the meanwhile.

What can I do to make it return?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can add a `CI=true` to the front of your command to force it to finish. Have a look at Arturo Mendes' comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61386453)

I hope this helps someone :)